# Update element in array if exists else insert new element in that array in MongoDb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm having group of array of element in MongoDB as given below :

```
{ 
    "_id" : 5, 
    "quizzes" : [
        {
            "wk" : 1, 
            "score" : 10
        }, 
        {
            "wk" : 2, 
            "score" : 8
        }, 
        {
            "wk" : 3, 
            "score" : 5
        }
      ], 
    "play" : [
        {
            "wk" : 2, 
            "score" : 8
        }, 
        {
            "wk" : 3, 
            "score" : 5
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying insert new record in array if not present and if record present in that array then update that array record.
Below is my MongoDB query.

```
db.push.update(
    { _id: 5 },
    { $push: { "quizzes": {"wk" : 6.0,"score" : 8.0},"play": {"wk" : 6.0,"score" : 8.0}  } }
)
```

Every time when i execute this query it inserts new record in array but i want if record present then update that array.

Comment: When you say *'if record present'*, do you mean record with same `wk` or same `score` or same `wk` & `score`?

Comment: same wk & score .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) instead of `$push`.

```
db.push.update(
    { _id: 5 },
    { $addToSet: { "quizzes": {"wk": 6.0, "score": 8.0}, "play": {"wk": 6.0, "score": 8.0} } }
)
```

---

**EDIT:**

There is no simple built-in approach for conditional sub-document update in an array field, by specific property. However, a small trick can do the job by executing two commands in sequence.

For example: If we want to update the `quizzes` field with the object `{ "wk": 7.0, "score": 8.0 }`, we can do it in two steps:

**Step-1:** `$pull` out sub-documents from the `quizzes` array where `"wk": 7.0`. (*Nothing happens if matching sub-document not found*).

```
db.push.update(
    { _id: 5 },
    { $pull: { "quizzes": { "wk": 7.0 } } }
)
```

**Step-2:** `$addToSet` the sub-document.

```
db.push.update(
    { _id: 5 },
    { $addToSet: { "quizzes": {"wk": 7.0, "score": 8.0} } }
)
```

You can combine the above two update commands using the [`bulk.find().update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/)

Comment: Santanu Biswas.. thanks for your response.kindly also let me know if in my array "wk" values is same but if "score " value get updated then i want to update that array value rather inserting new element in that array.

Comment: @user3720965 I wonder why you removed this as the correct reply!

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you want to do is,
add a property to an element of the array based on the same element's different property's value.

***You can use the `updateOne()` function with the `$(update)` operator, please refer the document [mongodb documentation for $(update)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).***

Let's say you want to add a property description to the array element where the value of wk is 1 (assuming its some kind of key based on what you have provided)

Input: Your data collection given in the question.

Mongo Command:

```
db.<your_collection_name>.updateOne(
{
 "_id":5,
   "quizzes.wk":1
  },
  {
   $set:{
    "quizzes.$.description":"I am a new property"
  }
});
```

Output:

```
{
        "_id" : 5,
        "quizzes" : [
                {
                        "wk" : 1,
                        "score" : 10,
                        "description" : "I am a new property"
                },
                {
                        "wk" : 2,
                        "score" : 8
                },
                {
                        "wk" : 3,
                        "score" : 5
                }
        ],
        "play" : [
                {
                        "wk" : 2,
                        "score" : 8
                },
                {
                        "wk" : 3,
                        "score" : 5
                }
        ]
}
```

Note: It will only change one entry of an array, the one which is matched first.