# MongoDB 4.2 update pipline. Query: "Push or Update" in nested aray

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want push new object to nested array if object with field 'Cat'=1 not exists. Or if object with 'Cat'=1 field exists then increment Up field in this object.

I cant write right syntax, help plz

**Document:**

```
{
  "BlogId" : 1,
  "Items" : [
    {
      "Cat" : 1,
      "Up" : 555,
    }, 
    {
      "Cat" : 2,
      "Up" : 666,
    }
  ]
}
```

**Query (with wrong syntax):**

```
db.exp.update({ BlogId: 1 }, 
[
  {
     $set: {
          "Items.Cat": {
            $cond: [ 
                     { "Items.Cat": 1 } , 
                     { $inc:  { "Items.Up": 1 } }, 
                     { $push: { "Items": { Cat: 1, Up: 555 }} } 
                   ]
          }
     }
  }
])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update element in array if exists else insert new element in that array in MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888312/update-element-in-array-if-exists-else-insert-new-element-in-that-array-in-mongo)

Comment: no. they only push. I need logic push or update