# Mongoose insert or update array item

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongoose

My model:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        name: { type: String, required: true, maxlength: 32, trim: true },
        email: { type: String, required: true, trim: true, unique: true },
        words: [Object]
    }
    , { timestamps: true }
    )
```

I want to add an object to the words array if it doesn't exist otherwise update the value of repeat_count.

This is the word object I want to add:
`var word = { word : "hello" , repeat_count : "12" }`

Is there any built-in function to do so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888312/update-element-in-array-if-exists-else-insert-new-element-in-that-array-in-mongo

Comment: I'm using mongoose

Answer (score 1):

first find your current object using id

```
 const findResponse = await this.{yourModel}.find(id);
```

then loop in your words array

```
   const index = findResponse.words.findIndex(
    (data) => data.word === word.word
  );

 let newData = {}
 let newArray = findResponse.words
if(index) {
      newArray[index] = word 

   else {
    newArray.push(word)
  }

   newData ={
      ...findResponse,
     words : newArray
     
   }
  const UpdateOrInsertData= new this.{yourModel}(newData);
  let saveResponse = await UpdateOrInsertData.save();
```